# Unable to start the application in SAP Cloud platform Cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform

After I deploy a Fiori application in cloud foundry environment and try to start the application, It is getting crashed. I tried to solve the issue with troubleshooting guide from the link below but couldn't solve the issue.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/troubleshoot-app-health.html

I updated the manifest.yml file as below.

```
---
applications:
- name: cf_fioriapp
  command: node my-app.js
  memory: 768M
  intances: 1
  buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
```

Below is the package.json file

```
{
    "name": "automate",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "This is the descripion for package.json file",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "1.0.1",
        "@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build": "1.3.33"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
    }
}
```

First, I ran the npm install command which downloaded node_modules. Then to push the app to cloud foundry, I ran the below command.

```
cf push cf_fioriapp -c "node my-app.js"
```

Below is the log file.

> 2018-04-24T11:14:09.06-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR module.js:478
>   2018-04-24T11:14:09.06-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     throw err;
>   2018-04-24T11:14:09.06-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     ^
>   2018-04-24T11:14:09.06-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Error: Cannot find
>   module '/home/vcap/app/my-app.js'    2018-04-24T11:14:09.06-0400
>   [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Function.Module._resolveFilename
>   (module.js:476:15)    2018-04-24T11:14:09.06-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
>   2018-04-24T11:14:09.06-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module.runMain
>   (module.js:611:10)    2018-04-24T11:14:09.06-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR
>   at run (bootstrap_node.js:387:7)    2018-04-24T11:14:09.06-0400
>   [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:153:9)
>   2018-04-24T11:14:09.06-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
>   bootstrap_node.js:500:3

Thanks,
Sankeerth

Comment: Is the issue still relevant or reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

From the buildpack output provided, it looks like the Node.js buildpack is trying to launch the application using a script called “start”. Potentially, this script is configured to be used in the app’s package.json under the “start” key (see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values). Alternatively, maybe the script exists but does not have the executable bit set?

Comment: I am trying to deploying this app to cloud foundry. Since I didn't configure any start script command in the package.json file, I hoped that the app should be started by its default start command. But it didn't work. However, the same app is working as expected in NEO environment. I am new to cloud foundry environment. Can you please help me?

Comment: Please include the log file for our reference.

Comment: Updated the question with log file. Please review

Answer (score 0):

I was able by modifying the manifest in 2 ways: add buildpack and add command.
Here my manifest.yalm:

```
---
applications:
- name: myapp
  command: node ./myapp/server.js
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
  random-route: true
  path: myapp
  memory: 128M
```

Also ./ in front of the path worked for me

```
---
applications:
- name: myapp
  random-route: true
  path: ./myapp
  memory: 128M
```

Regards
 Norman